# entrycomponents substitution in angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16

I've updated my project to Angular 16. In `app.module.ts`, I have an array of components named `entryComponents`. However, the `entryComponents` is no longer available in Angular 16. Where should I add these components to my project:

```
entryComponents:[
    PayResultDialogComponent,
    MessageBoxComponent
  ],
```

Comment: probably you just need to remove them, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: Yeap, it is no longer required. So removing it is enough to make the code work.

Comment: I need these components. `entryComponents` runs these components at runtime.

Comment: with Ivy(since angular 10) components factories can be found on ComponentClass.ɵfac, and you no longer need separate componentFactoryResolver and additional registrations for such components to be able to render them. just dropping entryComponents is safe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from version 10 of angular and quoting [angular update](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=9.1-10.0):

> In your application projects, you can remove `entryComponents` NgModules and any uses of `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS`. They are no longer required with the Ivy compiler and runtime. You may need to keep these if building a library that will be consumed by a View Engine application.

So in theory, you can simply remove these, since they are no longer needed.

If you still face errors, then you can try adding the respective `entryComponent` in the `declarations` array of the `@Ngmodule` or standalone component where they are used.